# Did the US government officially apologize for Indian Removal Act and Native American Indian genocide?

Tags: native-americans

Have the US government officially apologized for Indian Removal Act and Native American Indian genocide?

If yes, could you provide more information when did it happen and who (which president or other high US authority) did apologize?

Comment: Welcome to History.SE, Derfder! +1 for a good question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, albeit in a [fairly weaselly way](http://usgovinfo.about.com/b/2012/12/27/did-you-know-the-us-apologized-to-native-americans.htm) (it was tucked into the middle of an unrelated spending bill).

I'm guessing that there are legal issues here; a government-issued apology could potentially open the government up to lawsuits (which, of course, they could decline to entertain because they are the government, but that would potentially be a bad PR move).

For what it's worth, the US *did* apologize to [Japanese-Americans interred](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_American_internment) during World War II and even provided survivors with a small amount of money in reparations in 1988.

Comment: In defence of our illustrious elected weasels, rather a lot of important things get passed through Congress by being tacked onto "must pass" spending bills. The debate about wheather that's Right or not is probably off-topic here, but it is fairly common.